# Gulp Browserify ReferenceError: source is not defined

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I'm getting this odd error as the title.
The full message looks like this

> $ gulp browserify [01:21:03] Using gulpfile F:\CSC
>   Assignments\FinalProject\HotelProject\gulpfile.js [01:21:03] Starting
>   'browserify'... [01:21:03] 'browserify' errored after 15 ms [01:21:03]
>   ReferenceError: source is not defined
>       at Gulp. (F:\CSC Assignments\FinalProject\HotelProject\gulpfile.js:109:15)
>       at module.exports (F:\CSC Assignments\FinalProject\HotelProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (F:\CSC Assignments\FinalProject\HotelProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (F:\CSC Assignments\FinalProject\HotelProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (F:\CSC Assignments\FinalProject\HotelProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
>       at C:\Users\LUCKYLAM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
>       at startup (node.js:129:16)
>       at node.js:814:3

I'm new to this and after having spent a couple of hours figuring out what's causing the problem I have no idea what is wrong around here. Please help.

Here is my /app/js/script.js

```
require('angular');

var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify('./app/js/script.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('main.js'))

        // saves it the public/js/ directory
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/kk/'));
});
```

My folder structure[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you are missing one npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream): `vinyl-source-stream`.

Try to install it with `npm install vinyl-source-stream --save-dev` and require in your gulpfile.js like so:

```
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
```

Comment: You saved me. Thank you :)